# not able to open under [Authorize] page in dot net core

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm facing an issue of not opening page after login with Authorization.

This have registered the services in my `Program.cs`

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddCookie(options =>
                    {
                        options.LoginPath = "/home/index";
                    });
```

This is my login post `IActionResult` code

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginViewModel formData)
{
    try
    {
        if (formData != null)
        {
            var loginUser = await webApiService.PostAsync<LoginViewModel, UserRootModel>(formData, Constants.GetLogin);
            if (loginUser.code == 200)
            {
                var LogedIn = loginUser.User;
                string Role = string.Empty;
                if (LogedIn.IsAlive != null && LogedIn.IsAlive != false && LogedIn.IsAdmin != false && LogedIn.IsAdmin != null)
                    Role = "Administrator";
                else
                    Role = "User";
                var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, LogedIn.Id),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, Role),
                };
                var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties();
                if (LogedIn.IsAdmin == true)
                {
                    authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
                    {
                        RedirectUri = TempData["ReturnUrl"]?.ToString() ?? "/admin/dashboard",
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
                    {
                        RedirectUri = TempData["ReturnUrl"]?.ToString() ?? "/dashboard/dashboard",
                    };
                }
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserId", LogedIn.Id);
                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                    new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), authProperties);
                return Json(new { url = authProperties.RedirectUri, message = loginUser.message });
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { message = loginUser.message });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { message = "Login credentials reqired, Please enter email and password." });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { message = "Something went wrong please try again." });

    }
}
```

this my JavaScript code for hit login post

```
$("#submitSignIn").click(function () {
    var Return = validationSignIn();
    if (Return) {
        loaderShow();
        var Email = $("#Email").val();
        var Password = $("#Password").val();

        var URL = "/User/Login";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: URL,
            data: JSON.stringify({
                Email: Email,
                Password: Password
            }),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                debugger
                if (data.url !== undefined) {
                    //if (data.url != window.location.href && window.location.pathname != "/") {
                        loaderHide();
                        SweetSuccessAlert("Login", data.message + "ly loged in.");
                        window.location.replace(data.url); 
                        //window.location.reload()
                    //}
                    //else {
                    //    loaderHide();
                    //    SweetSuccessAlert("Login", data.message + "ly loged in.");
                    //    window.location.href = data.url
                    //}
                }
                else {
                    loaderHide();
                    SweetErrorAlert("Oops...", data.message);
                }
            },
            error: function (errorMsg) {
                loaderHide();
                console.log(errorMsg);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

After login, when I'm opening any [Authorize] it still taking me on *https://localhost:61378/home/index?ReturnUrl=%2Fuser%2Fsettings* url which should not be the case if I am already logged in.

```
[Authorize]
  public async Task<IActionResult> settings()
  {
      try
      {
          string UserId = HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserId");
          UserModel loginUser = new();
          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserId))
          {
              var Userroot = await webApiService.GetAsync<UserRootModel>(Constants.GetUser + UserId);
              if (Userroot != null)
              {
                  loginUser = Userroot.User;
                  return View(loginUser);
              }
              else
              { return Json(new { message = "Something went wrong please try again." }); }

          }
          else
          {
              return Json(new { message = "Something went wrong please try again." });
          }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          return Json(new { message = "Something went wrong please try again." });

      }
  }
```

I don't know what's wrong going on here, which cannot be able to active [Authorize] pages.

Comment: @QingGuo if i remove options.LoginPath = "/home/index"; then if user not login then try to access page it will not return to home/index?ReturnUrl=%2Fuser%2Fsettings if user not loged in

Comment: Is your JavaScript code  code in your Index view ?

Comment: @QingGuo i need a logic in JavaScript  if im login from home page then it will take im on dashboard   if in login with any other page then it will keep me on same page but now there is one case

Comment: @QingGuo  iif user not loged in there is url like i.e. https://localhost:61378/home/index?ReturnUrl=%2Fuser%2Fsettings if user login in this case then it will take me on /user/settings page as i.e have ReturnUrl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test your code, find the reason, you may miss `app.UseAuthentication();`, try to add `app.UseAuthentication();` before `app.UseAuthorization();` in Program.cs:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

result:
[image]

Comment: thank you yes you are right I was added app.UseAuthentication(); on wring place now it is working after placing it correct place it need to be